# PHP variable variable value in echo

Tags: php

I have a variable variable in PHP.

My Code is

```
$a1 = "phase";

$phase = $phaseData["Body"]["Data"]["Value"];
```

I use `$$a1` and the code works fine but when I use echo or print to view what's going on it displays the wording `$phase` not the value of `$phaseData`

How do i get the print or echo to show the value of `$phaseData` when using `$$a1`?

I use this code to to display

```
Echo "A1 \t $$a1\n";
```

Comment: How do you make an echo?

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: `$phaseData` is not set in your code. Also, no `echo`. Or do you want to output `$phaseData` as a string?

Comment: Have you tried putting the variable in {}?
Echo "A1 \t ${$a1}\n";

Comment: @kerbholz
Apologies for not giving all the details and being slow on response, Still learning Stack exchange.
have updated question with relevant information

Comment: @Mark_1
 I haven't, I really don't know much about PHP at all.
i gave it a try but my data is down atm. it showed blank atm which is a good sign.
Will let you know tomorrow when i can test again to see if it works. it looks promising though. Cheers,

Comment: It worked thanks @mark_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something here? $phase  is never defined. Even $phase is defined, $phaseData is not. I guess you want to do this:

```
$a1 = "phase";
$phase = "ABCD";

$phase2 = "${$a1}Data";
echo $phase2;
echo "\n";
//or
$phase3 = $$a1. "Data";
echo $phase3;
echo "\n";
```

Another example:

```
$a = "AAA";
$b = "BBB";
$c = "CCC";

$array = array ('a', 'b', 'c');

foreach ($array as $item) {
  echo "\nPrint $item:" . $item;
  echo "\nPrint $a:" . ${$item};
}

echo "\n";

output: 
Print a:a    
Print AAA:AAA    
Print b:b    
Print AAA:BBB    
Print c:c    
Print AAA:CCC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks like   `echo "\nPrint $a:" . ${$item};` may work i was a little confused with the code until mark pointed out out the same thing but typed in my code and then looking at yours made sense. im very new to PHP and coding in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `echo` the *value* of `$phaseData` you'd need to set it first:

```
<?php
$a1 = "phase";
$phaseData = 'test';
$phase = "$phaseData";
echo $$a1;
```

Will output `test`.

---

If you want your script to output `$phaseData` you need to change your quotes to single quotes, so `$phaseData` doesn't get parsed:

```
<?php
$a1 = "phase";
$phase = '$phaseData';
echo $$a1;
```

Will output `$phaseData`.

Comment: its doing the second option  but i have set `$phasedata` first

Answer (score 0):

`Echo "A1 \t ${$a1}\n";` worked
I just needed the brackets